# How can i remove the filename and the ? from the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have managed to remove the extension from the url and got it looking up using a slug not product_code.  My question now is how do i remove the ?name from the url.  e.g.
http://www.adlantic.ie/product?name=safety-knee-pad

Preferably would love to have it just:
http://www.adlantic.ie/product=safety-knee-pad

my htaccess atm looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product(?:\.php)?\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ product=%1? [R=302,L,NE]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^product=(.+)$ product?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: got the following error:  Not Found

The requested URL /product=lanyards/domed-ski-pass-holder was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: ok, very strange.  Does a great job on the url ( http://www.adlantic.ie/product=sweets/click-clack) but all the styling disappears

Comment: That is due to relative paths in css/js. For that you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`